# Finding Maximum query result using spring-data-jpa @Query annotation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is is possible to limit query results using .setMaxResults(1).getResultList() and @Query - something like:

```
@Query("SELECT l FROM LocationLog l WHERE l.visit = :visit ORDER BY l.eventTime").setMaxResults(1).getResultList()
public LocationLog findLast(@Param("visit") Visit visit);
```

This code is not correct as the setMaxResults and so on is outside the @Query?l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set pagination options in `@Query` annotation, but it can be done in other way. You can change your method declaration to

```
public LocationLog find(@Param("visit") Visit visit, Pageable pageable);
```

Then you will be able to pass additional argument to query invocation:

```
Pageable firstFive = new PageRequest(0, 5);
LocationLog locLog = locationLogDao.find(visit, firstFive);
```

There's also option to know current context of the query results you can use `Page` interface changing method return type to `Page<LocationLog>`. You can find all necessary informations [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/).